# ASP.Net MVC View with RadioButtonList with Other freeformat selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am putting together questionairre for registering for an event.

One of the eventr registration questions is:

```
What is your main job function?
    Director/MD/Owner
    Manager
    Team Leader
    Other: Please state
```

I would like this to show as a drop down box, or a radio button list in my view, but also with a textbox underneath or next to the "Other" radiobutton, so that a free form "Other" job function can be entered.  How would I bind this in my view?

I suspect my model will contain:

```
    [Display(Name = "What is your main job function?")]
    public string JobFunction { get; set; }
```

...where JobFunction get's populated by the selected item above.  But how in my controller, would I override the selected item, if it's "Other" and substitute it with the text box on the view?

I'm sure this has been done many times before - so thank you for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach of many would be this:

View:

```
  <div id="sample-dropdown">
    <select name="JobFunction " id="JobFunction" class="dropdown">
        <option value="Director/MD/Owner">Director/MD/Owner</option>
        <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
        <option value="Team Leader" selected="selected">Team Leader</option>
        <option value="Other">Other: Please state</option>   
    </select>
    <input name="JobFunctionOther" id="JobFunctionOther" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[name="JobFunctionOther"]').hide();
        $(function() {
                $("#JobFunction").change(
                    function() {
                        var val = $(this).val();
                        if (val =='Other') {
                            $('input[name="JobFunctionOther"]').show();

                        } else {
                            $('input[name="JobFunctionOther"]').hide();
                        }

                    }).change();
            });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult DropDown(string jobFunction, string jobFunctionOther)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobFunctionOther)) jobFunction = jobFunctionOther;
    //do what you do
    return View(jobFunction);
}
```